# Automatically create unit test playlist

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

We have a multiple class files in a unit test project. Is it possible to automatically create a unit test playlist for a class file. E.g. for Test class A there should be a playlist called TestClassA playlist.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks